# Charge on Earth

Tags: electrostatics, charge, earth, geophysics

We know that the Earth is neutral. But what will happen if the Earth becomes negatively charged or positively charged somehow?

Comment: How do you know the earth is neutral?  It is continuously being bombarded by cosmic rays (many of which are charged) and I doubt the ratio of negative to positive charges is one-to-one.  Many parts of the earth carry charge (clouds during thunder storms) so how could we ever tell?

Comment: @user10379 You might want to check this question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3955/

Comment: This is a fun question :) Before I attempt an answer, could I please clarify a few things: does the earth get charged instantaneously? how charged does it get (enough to effect the other planets?)? and finally, which bit of the earth is charged (e.g. land, sea or atmosphere)?

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91556/2451

Comment: Also related: https://what-if.xkcd.com/140/