# Why the Earth isn't negatively charged?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, earth, lightning

As electricity is transferred in earth by earthing and lightning, why it does not become negatively charged?

Comment: Why do you think it does not become negatively charged?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the net charge of the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3955/what-is-the-net-charge-of-the-earth)

Answer (score -1):

The mass and volume of the Earth is very large containing many atoms. Any addition or removal of charge causes the charges to redistribute themselves over this large volume which effectively remains neutral.